# como puedo resolver estecon array javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Hola como puedo hacer un nuevo arreglo que me muestre los nombre de los jugadores con la cantidad total de horas jugadas ordenadas de manera decreciente?

```
const jugadores = [
 { id:1, nombre: 'javier'},
 { id:2, nombre: 'pedro'},
 { id:3, nombre: 'jesus'},
]
 
const horasjugadas = [ 
 { jugador: 1, consola: 1, juego: 1, año: 2019, horas: 40 },
 { jugador: 2, consola: 2, juego: 2, año: 2020, horas: 10 },
 { jugador: 3, consola: 3, juego: 3, año: 2021, horas: 10 },
 { jugador: 1, consola: 2, juego: 1, año: 2019, horas: 20 },
 { jugador: 2, consola: 1, juego: 2, año: 2020, horas: 40 },
 { jugador: 3, consola: 3, juego: 3, año: 2022, horas: 50 },
]
```

Comment: Lo primero que debes hacer vuandp estas aprendiendona programar, como parece ser tu caso, es tener la disciplina para intentar resolver por ti mismo los ejercicios que te plantean tus tutores. El proposito de cada ehercicio es precisamente ejercitar tu razonamiento

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento. [**Aquí no hacemos tareas**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4320), ni se dan tutoriales. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: ya lo resolvi! gracias por la ayuda